# Reduce integer linear program constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraints

I currently have defined a pure integer linear program that works well, but the number of constraints for a given input  runs out of time and/or memory. Let me introduce the problem.

I have an adjacent matrix $C$ of size $N \times N$, where each component $c_{ij} = 1$  if locations $i$ and $j$ can be connected and $0$ otherwise, and where $0 \leq i,j \leq N$. So let's suppose that I have a matrix with $N = 3$ like:

\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\1&1&0\\1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}

This means that:

Location 1 can be connected with location 1 (itself), 2 and 3.
Location 2 can be connected with location 1 and 2 (itself), but not 3.
Location 3 can be connected with location 1 and 3 (itself), but not 2.

Each of my ILP variables are denoted by $x_{ij}$. So $x_{ij} = 1$ if locations $i,j$ are connected and 0 otherwise. My objective is to have up to K locations connected, respecting the adjacent matrix.

$x_{ii} = 1$ denotes that location $i$ is a root. My linear program looks like this:

f: min $\sum_{i\in N} x_{ii}$

such that:

1) $\sum_{i}x_{ii} \leq K$ (up to K roots)

2) $\forall i \sum_{j} x_{ij} = 1$ (a location can only belongs to a root).

3) $\forall i, x_{ii} + \sum_{j} c_{ij}x_{ij}x_{jj} = 1$. it denotes whether a location is a root or a leaf.

4) $\forall i,j,w (1 - x_{iw}) + (1 - x_{jw}) + c_{ij} \geq 1$. This is the problematic constraints. It means to denote transitivity. If $c_{ij} = 1$, then we have to check if $i$ and $j$ belongs to the same root $w$. It checks if locations $i,w$ and $jw$ can be connected if $i,j$ can be connected as well.

This means that I cannot have a connection {1,2,3} because {2,3} or {3,2} cannot be connected. So, although 1 can be connected with 2 and 3, since 2 and 3 are not compatibles, I cannot connect those locations.

A possible solution for K = 2 is {1,2}, {3} or {1,3}, {2}. For K = 1 there is not feasible solution.

The problem is that if I have a matrix C of for example size N = 100, then constraint 4) is 100*100*100 = 1000000 constraints. For matrices of 300/400, then it is intractable.

All variables must take values between 0 and 1.

Any idea about how can I check transitivity without having this huge amount of constraints? The problem is $\forall i,j,w$.

Thank you very much. Any idea will be really appreciated.

EDIT: Linear version of the quadratic program:

1) $\forall{i} \in S, x_{ii} + \sum_{j\in S-\{i\}}c_{ij}y_{ij} = 1 $

2) $\forall{i,j,k} \in S, (1-x_{ik}) + (1-x_{jk}) + c_{ij} \geq 1 $

3) $ \forall{i }\in S, \sum_{j \in S} x_{ij} = 1 $

4) $ \forall{i \in S}, \sum_{i\in S} x_{ii} \leq k $

5) $ \forall{i,j \in S}, y_{ij} \geq x_{ij} + x_{jj} - 1 $

6) $ \forall{i,j \in S}, y_{ij} \leq x_{ij}$

7) $ \forall{i,j \in S}, y_{ij} \leq x_{jj}$

8) $ \forall{i,j \in S}, x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$

9) $ \forall{i,j \in S}, y_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$

Comment: In other words, you want to partition the nodes of a graph into a minimum number of cliques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraint 3 is only an expression with no equality or inequality.  It sounds like your graph is undirected, in which case you need to define variables $x_{i,j}$ only for $i \le j$ with $c_{i,j}=1$ instead of all $(i,j)\in N \times N$.  There are then 3 transitivity constraints for each triple $i<j<k$:
\begin{align}
x_{i,j} + x_{i,k} -1&\le x_{j,k} \\
x_{i,j} + x_{j,k} -1&\le x_{i,k} \\
x_{i,k} + x_{j,k} -1&\le x_{i,j}
\end{align}

Another approach is to recognize that this problem is minimum node clique cover, which is equivalent to chromatic number of the graph complement, as discussed [in this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398786/minimum-clique-cover-via-mip).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry. Constraint 3 is an equality constraint. I already have edited it.

Comment: OK, but the edited constraint 3 is not linear.

Comment: That's true. I already linearised the constraint. But still the problem is constraint 4), the transitivity constraint. (Constraint 2) in the ILP version)

Comment: So, if I have N = 500. Then I have 500^3 transitivity constraints (125000000 constraints). Which is intractable

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are trying to partition the nodes into a minimum number of cliques?

Comment: Sorry, I was reading a little bit about this. I think it is a minimum clique cover problem. Although instead of minimizing the number of cliques (here are clusters or roots), I want to find a number of cliques $\leq K$

Comment: Now that I see the post that you sent me, I think yes, is a minimum node click cover. So the number of constraints will be the same: N^3. Isn't it?

Comment: No, the number of transitivity constraints is 3 times the number of triangles in $G$, which might be much less than $N^3$.  But I think you will have better performance with the formulation that I gave in the linked post.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Now I am even more curious about this. SO, assuming that is a node clique cover: \begin{align}
x_{i,c} &\le z_c \\ 
x_{i,c} + x_{j,c} &\le 1 &&\text{if $(i,j)\not\in E$}\\
\sum_c x_{i,c} &= 1
\end{align} And assuming that $i < j$ and $c \in N$ right?